# can I use a 5v 1a charger with a 5v 2a device?

Tags: charger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

I have a new tablet with a charger that reads 5v 2a, can I charge the tablet with my phone charger, which reads 5v 1a? Thanks!

Comment: this site has both search and a FAQ - two mouse clicks took me to this. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: Actually this is *not* a duplicate of the above, as here the proposed charger has a *lower* current rating than the one it is replacing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The question is explaining what the ratings mean, not specifically calling out the rating. If you feel that question could be better please edit it, but that question is there so that we dont have to answer this question with different numbers over and over and over.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Meta please :)

Answer (score 5):

Using the 5V 1A charger to operate a device that is normally charged with a 5V 2A charger is a bad idea. The smaller rated 1A charger is likely to overheat when used in this manner. In the worst case it could even catch fire so don't do this.